# html and text format

Tags: html, css

I am trying to copy paste text (title, paragraph, spacing & line) from word file to html / div.
however, when I tried to do that,
title
paragraph
spacing & line
were not display same as word file.

here is my paragraph

"Chapter 100 - Hello

Well, that day is arguably the darkest day in my sister's life, because you used to be a brutal force that everyone knew, no one looked down on you, no one took care of you, but my sister, Walking with you, holding your hand on campus, shopping with you, eating with you, do you know what other people call my sister?

I heard it, everyone called her like this, ridiculed her, and then, she felt nothing. But afterwards, a girl's self-esteem is always necessary. My sister is fed up, and she feels that God is unfair. , Yeah, she abandoned you and broke up with you!"

***here is my code***

Chapter 100 - Hello

Well, that day is arguably the darkest day in my sister's life, because you used to be a brutal force that everyone knew, no one looked down on you, no one took care of you, but my sister, Walking with you, holding your hand on campus, shopping with you, eating with you, do you know what other people call my sister?

I heard it, everyone called her like this, ridiculed her, and then, she felt nothing. But afterwards, a girl's self-esteem is always necessary. My sister is fed up, and she feels that God is unfair. , Yeah, she abandoned you and broke up with you!

---

however, in stack overflow,
title
paragraph
spacing & line
are display as same as world file

***in my browser it display as***

Chapter 100 - Hello Well, that day is arguably the darkest day in my sister's life, because you used to be a brutal force that everyone knew, no one looked down on you, no one took care of you, but my sister, Walking with you, holding your hand on campus, shopping with you, eating with you, do you know what other people call my sister? I heard it, everyone called her like this, ridiculed her, and then, she felt nothing. But afterwards, a girl's self-esteem is always necessary. My sister is fed up, and she feels that God is unfair. , Yeah, she abandoned you and broke up with you!

***it is completely different and I don't know what is happening***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `white-space: pre-wrap;` on your `div`.

> Sequences of white space are preserved. Lines are broken at newline characters, at 
> , and as necessary to fill line boxes.

```css
.a { white-space: pre-wrap }
```

```html
<div class="a">
Chapter 100 - Hello

Well, that day is arguably the darkest day in my sister's life, because you used to be a brutal force that everyone knew, no one looked down on you, no one took care of you, but my sister, Walking with you, holding your hand on campus, shopping with you, eating with you, do you know what other people call my sister?

I heard it, everyone called her like this, ridiculed her, and then, she felt nothing. But afterwards, a girl's self-esteem is always necessary. My sister is fed up, and she feels that God is unfair. , Yeah, she abandoned you and broke up with you!
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you use Pre and p tag it will work

```
<h4>
    "Chapter 100 - Hello
</h4>
<p>
    Well, that day is arguably the darkest day in my sister's life, because you used to be a brutal force that
    everyone knew, no one looked down on you, no one took care of you, but my sister, Walking with you, holding your
    hand on campus, shopping with you, eating with you, do you know what other people call my sister?
</p>
<p>
    I heard it, everyone called her like this, ridiculed her, and then, she felt nothing. But afterwards, a girl's
    self-esteem is always necessary. My sister is fed up, and she feels that God is unfair. , Yeah, she abandoned
    you and broke up with you!"
</p>
```

> pre Tag

```
  
Chapter 100 - Hello


Well, that day is arguably the darkest day in my sister's life, because you used to be a brutal force that everyone knew, no one looked down on 
you, no one took care of you, but my sister, Walking with you, holding your hand on campus, shopping with you, eating with you, do you know what other people call my sister?

I heard it, everyone called her like this, ridiculed her, and then, she felt nothing. But afterwards, a girl's self-esteem is always necessary. My sister
is fed up, and she feels that God is unfair. , Yeah, she abandoned you and broke up with you!"
```